# I need to stop repeating rows from Mysql Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

I have two sql tables 
1) employee {`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `job_title`, `salary`}
2) education {`id`, `name`}

once I tried to get data from this two tables by this query I am getting repeating rows like this

```
first name  last name   qualification
Robin        Jackman    BSc
Taylor        Edward    BSc
Vivian       Dickens    MSc
Vivian       Dickens    PhD

$query = "SELECT emp.first_name, emp.last_name, edu.name AS edu_name 
          FROM `employee` AS emp 
          LEFT JOIN `employee_education` AS ee ON emp.id = ee.employee_id 
          LEFT JOIN `education` AS edu ON ee.education_id = edu.id";
```

**But My expected result is like this**

```
first name  last name   qualification
Robin        Jackman    BSc
Taylor        Edward    BSc
Vivian       Dickens    MSc PhD
```

Do you have any idea of how to get this done? 
Thank You.

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`job_title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`salary` double DEFAULT NULL,
`notes` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `employee` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `job_title`, `salary`) VALUES 
('Robin', 'Jackman', 'Software Engineer', 5500),
('Taylor', 'Edward', 'Software Architect', 7200),
('Vivian', 'Dickens', 'Database Administrator', 6000),
('Harry', 'Clifford', 'Database Administrator', 6800),
('Eliza', 'Clifford', 'Software Engineer', 4750),
('Nancy', 'Newman', 'Software Engineer', 5100),
('Melinda', 'Clifford', 'Project Manager', 8500),
('Harley', 'Gilbert', 'Software Architect', 8000);


CREATE TABLE `education` (
`id` tinyint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `education` (`name`) VALUES ('BSc'), ('MSc'), ('PhD');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to combine the names:

```sql
SELECT emp.first_name, emp.last_name, GROUP_CONCAT(edu.name ORDER BY edu.name SEPARATOR ' ') AS edu_name 
FROM `employee` AS emp 
LEFT JOIN `employee_education` AS ee ON emp.id = ee.employee_id 
LEFT JOIN `education` AS edu ON ee.education_id = edu.id
GROUP BY emp.id
```

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 Where does the question specify the order of the qualifications?

Comment: After trying it in my local DB, Igot PhD printed out before Msc as the result of `group_concat`. I read the expected result, and this oder where `Msc` comes before `PhD` can be achieved by either ordering it by `edu.name` or `edu.id` (maybe this is more reliable).

Comment: You figured out a general rule like that from one row in the example?

Comment: well, I am indeed a little bit skeptical sometimes =)